# ::selection not working correctly on line break

Tags: html, css

I am using `::selection` to alter the color of the highlight, since the default blue doesn't really work in my color theme. However, when I have multiline text with `<br>` (or `\n` from js, which just gets converted to `<br>`) the line breaks are always the default blue.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>
      <div class="selector">Try<br>selecting<br>me.</div>
</body>
<style>
.selector::selection {
    background-color: #8d8d8d;
}
</style>
</html>
```

How can I make *all* the selected text including line breaks the same color?

Comment: If it's not working, I'm guessing that it's not working on Chrome (?) because it _is_ working on Firefox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an additional `.selector *::selection` selector to the css that will define all child elements inside `.selector`.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>
      <div class="selector">Try<br>selecting<br>me.</div>
</body>
<style>
.selector::selection,
.selector *::selection {
    background-color: #8d8d8d;
}
</style>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
  <head>
  <style>
    .selector::selection, .selector *::selection {
      background-color: #8d8d8d;
    }
  </style>
  </head>
  <body>
        <div class="selector">Try<br>selecting<br>me.</div>
  </body>
  </html>
```